# Panel help with little program

Tags: slideshows

I'd like to show the output of this program into one large `Panel`, but when I surround this code with `Panel[ ]`, it doesn't seem to work. Why is that?

```
listA = {};
listB = {};
"Verzameling A : " InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[listA, #] &]] 

"Verzameling B : " InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[listB, #] &]]


listAShow := Sort[ DeleteDuplicates[listA]];
listBShow := Sort[ DeleteDuplicates[listB]];

"Verzameling A =" Dynamic[listAShow]
"Verzameling B =" Dynamic[listBShow]

unie := Union[listAShow, listBShow];
doorsnede := Intersection[listAShow, listBShow];

toonOpl = False;
Row@{Checkbox[Dynamic[toonOpl]], "Toon bewerkingen"}
Dynamic[If[toonOpl,
  Column@{
    Row@{"Unie van A en B = ", unie}
    , Row@{"Doorsnede van A en B = ", doorsnede}
    }, {}]]

Button["Reset alles", listA = {}; listB = {}]
```

Thanks all!

Comment: @Kuba Hehe... took me some time to understand, how you *heard him singing* in the post ;-)

Comment: @halirutan fortunatelly I've corrected that typo before [ruebenko commented it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31638/5478) :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Post formatted... All help appreciated on the panel!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all the code lines which display output into a `Column`:

```
listA = {};
listB = {};
listAShow := Sort[DeleteDuplicates[listA]];
listBShow := Sort[DeleteDuplicates[listB]];
unie := Union[listAShow, listBShow];
doorsnede := Intersection[listAShow, listBShow];
toonOpl = False;

Panel@Column@{
   "Verzameling A : " InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[listA, #] &]],
   "Verzameling B : " InputField[Dynamic[Null, AppendTo[listB, #] &]],
   "Verzameling A =" Dynamic[listAShow], 
   "Verzameling B =" Dynamic[listBShow], 
   Row@{Checkbox[Dynamic[toonOpl]], "Toon bewerkingen"}, 
   Dynamic[If[toonOpl, 
     Column@{Row@{"Unie van A en B = ", unie}, 
       Row@{"Doorsnede van A en B = ", doorsnede}}, {}]], 
   Button["Reset alles", listA = {}; listB = {}]}
```

[image]